# ProviderError: transaction underpriced on Mumbai Testnet

Tags: solidity, nft

I am building an NFT Market on the Polygon network.

I am able to deploy my code on localhost and everything works fine.

But when I try to it deploy to the mumbai testnet using the command
**npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mumbai**

I run into this error.
**ProviderError: transaction underpriced**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually I too got this error in morning. Somehow I believe default gasPrice is not picked up. So I just updated my hardhat config file with following :-

```
mumbai: {
      // Infura
      url: `https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [privateKey1],
      gasPrice: 35000000000,
      saveDeployments: true,
    },
```

Earlier I was not using gasPrice explicitly. When I put some value it, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using the wrong RPC node, sharing just in case someone made the same mistake as I did

**How did I fix it?**

1. Removed Matic chain from Metamask networks
2. Added it again from https://umbria.network/connect/matic-testnet-mumbai

Answer (score 0):

**UNDERPRICED** [REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED]

Official doc: *https://docs.ethers.org/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED*

> *To prevent nodes from being overloaded with junk transactions, a transaction is only accepted into the memory pool if it has a reasonable chance of being actually mined, which means that the account has sufficient balance, the nonce is correct and the fee seems reasonable.*

**Summary:** is related to 3 issues on a transaction:

- Insufficient balance
- Incorrect nonce
- Low fee

**Solutions**:

- Increase deployer account balance. Either using a faucet or purchasing ETH.
- Increase nonce value (***simplified**: number of transactions +1*)
- Increase transaction fee (setting higher gasPrice)

Official documentation: *https://docs.ethers.org/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED*